# count the highest consecutive occurrence of a string in Python

Tags: python, string

How can I find the maximum number of occurrences of a string in python?
for example if string s is :

```
s="**hellohellohello**applefruitcat**hellohello**lionlizard**hellohellohellohello**"
```

and I'm looking for the max number of consecutive "hello"
this should return 4 since the max number of consecutive occurrence of hello is 4

I came up with a code to test the find function and surprisingly it gives me 4 which is the maximum number of consecutive occurrence I also tried different strings and it gave me the correct maximum. What I don't understand here is how is it returning the max number of occurrences, if no max function is used? I thought it would return how many times hello was found.

this is the code:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
if s.find('hello' * i) != -1:
    x = i
```

Comment: When i is varing,it finds ("hello"*i)....as an example,if i=3,it finds "hellohellohello" from the string.If it found, s.find('hello' * i) return the position of it(>0)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet loops over consecutive concatenated "hello"s. It first checks if there's a "hello" in the string, then "hellohello", etc, until it fails. The longest sequence that was there is the max number of consecutive "hello"s.

Comment: so basically this part : ('hello' * i) != -1 
keeps checking until it finds the longest sequences and returns it? I was confused because I thought it would count all the "hellos" in the string

Comment: Note the `* i` - in each iteration it looks for `hello` concatenated `i` times, until it can't find one (and `-1` is returned).

Answer (score 0):

The code loops over the length of the string trying to find 'hello' then 'hellohello' and so on. It will set x to the current value of i if it found that many repetitions.

It will still search for 'hello'*5 and 'hello'*6 in your case but won't find it in the string thus leaving x to the last value of i it could actually find.

A slightly better version would be:

```
for i in range(len(s)/len('hello')):
  if s.find('hello' * i) != -1:
    x = i
```